# working with huge int represented as string

Tags: python-3.x

Learning Python just for two months, so please be patient .)

Stumbled at very interesting task - perform arithmetic operations with huge numbers `( n: int, number of digits < 10**6 )`, represented as str `( len(str) < 10**6 )`. I need to split this string in parts, make some simple arithmetics, and give output back as string. Converting to int and back takes about 0.5 sec:

```
from time import time
from random import choice

string = ''
digits = [str(i) for i in range(10)]

for _ in range(1, 99999):
    string += choice(digits)

start = time()
a, b = string[:50000], string[50000:]  # Split in half
a, b = map(int, [a, b])
print('str to int:', time() - start)
# Output: str to int: 0.1092...

c = a + b

start = time()
output = ''.join([str(part) for part in [a, b, c]])
print('int to str:', time() - start)
# Output: int to str: 0.4836...
```

Problem starts when I need to perform this operation in a loop with **hundreds** iterations

This is something about reverse hashing-like functions

My simple question is this - what kind of optimisation is possible for this kind of situation?

With my best regards! .)

Comment: Check out this site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ not really suitable as it's not quite explained what the OP is trying to achieve and how relevant this splitting in half thing is...

Comment: What tasks are you trying to achieve and is your concern purely the str<->int conversions or something else? What's the set of operations you'd like to perform on these numbers?

Comment: @jon-clements, here is link to a task: http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/898/F

Answer (score 0):

Vadim, I can't answer your question directly. However, let me point you towards the [gmpy2 library](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mpz.html). The principal author is one of the outrageously clever people we used to see often here on SO; you could use gmpy2 itself, or have a look at the source code.

```
>>> from gmpy2 import *
>>> s = '012345678901234'
>>> t = '123456789012345'
>>> N = mpz(s)+mpz(t)
>>> N
mpz(135802467913579)
>>> str(N)
'135802467913579'
```